# hint text turns to real text in EditText after device rotation

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have a EditText View with some hint text.

When the device rotates the hint turns to real text.

If the user has written some text before - it's overridden.

How can I change the behavior? stop the hint from turning into text?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with saving data across rotation. Basically, your data is destroyed on rotation.

To fix this issue, you need to save the data you have across runtime configuration change(rotation in this case).

One way to do this is to override the `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` in your Activity.

The method I described above is called before `onPause()` `onStop()` and `onDestroy()`

From a good book I read:

The default implementation of onSaveInstanceState(…) asks all of the activity’s views to
save their state as data in the Bundle object. A Bundle is a structure that maps string keys to
values of certain limited types
You have seen this Bundle before. It is passed into onCreate(Bundle)

`@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//
}`

When you override onCreate(…), you call onCreate(…) on the activity’s superclass and pass
in the bundle you just received. In the superclass implementation, the saved state of the views is
retrieved and used to recreate the activity’s view hierarchy.

Here is the cool part..

You will need to override onSavedInstanceState to save additional data  to your bundle and then READ that data back in the `onCreate()` method.

So, whatever data you want to save across rotation, you need to add that data to this bundle.

Do that like this..

Add a constant that will act as a key that will be stored in the bundle.

`private static final String MY_KEY = "My Key";`

Then override `onSaveInstanceState()` to write the value of your data to the bundle with the constant `MY_KEY`  as the key.

`@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
savedInstanceState.putInt(MY_KEY, YOUR DATA THAT YOU KEEP LOSING ON ROTATION GOES HERE!!!!!);
}`

and lastly in `onCreate` check for this value and if it exists assign it to your variable.

`if (savedInstanceState != null) {
TheTextThatYouKeepLosing = savedInstanceState.getInt(MY_KEY, 0);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Could be helpful in case you are doing the same how I did, posting as an answer to have some formatting.

I had the exactly same issue. I was adding `fragment` into `activity` in `onCreate` like below

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment, fragment, tag);
```

Due to this whenever I rotate the device was facing the exact same issue as you have mentioned, then I did double check and found the issue that on each rotation fragment was getting added.

In my case solution was to just replace `add` with `replace` like below. After doing this problem got resolved.

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.toDoFragment, fragment, tag);
```